# An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'UIActivityIndicatorView' object

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uiactivityindicatorview, nszombie

When running my app on device, it crashes right when I initiate my `AvPlayer` to stream an mp3. However, it works fine on simulator.

I have tried to run it through Zombie and I get the following error message when it crashes : "An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'UIActivityIndicatorView' object (zombie) at address: 0x108c020e0"

I am using an Activity indicator in previous scenes but I have tried to remove it completely, leaving no line of code mentioning any `UIActivityIndicatorView` and I still get the same error.

Any idea of how to deal with this? Can it be linked to the system activity indicator displayed the status bar?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I'm also seeing this. Looks like an iOS bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a crash because of abusing appearance API not as documenting (setting a property not marked with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`).

For reference, see [here](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController/issues/71#issuecomment-222838020).